# Why do all my jQuery mobile .on() instructions autofire on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm currently making a little mobile web-app based on the jQuery mobile framework that is supposed to load a bunch of pages that the user can swipe left or right or touch/click the "Previous"/"Next" buttons to browse. So my code looks like this :

```
function next(destination) {
    alert('next'); // for testing purpose
    $.mobile.changePage(destination, {
        transition: "slide"
    });
}

function prev(destination) {
    alert('prev'); // for testing purpose
    $.mobile.changePage(destination, {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
    });
}


$(window).load(function(){

    $("#btn_next1").on("click", next("index.html#pagetwo"));
    $("#btn_prev2").on("click", prev("index.html#pageone"));
    $("#btn_next2").on("click", next("index.html#pagethree"));
    $("#btn_prev3").on("click", prev("index.html#pageone"));
    $("#pageone").on("swipeleft", next("index.html#pagetwo"));
    $("#pagetwo").on("swipeleft", next("index.html#pagethree"));
    $("#pagetwo").on("swiperight", prev("index.html#pageone"));
    $("#pagethree").on("swiperight", prev("index.html#pagetwo"));

});
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong but when I try this on my browser, I all the ".on()" instructions fire on start without waiting for my clicks or swipes so I get  alerts, each one followed by a page change with the right transition. I also tried to put these instructions outside "$(window).load()".

I need your help if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe show me an easier way to do this. Thank you

Comment: use page events, dont use `.load()` to attach events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're missing all the anonymous functions that create the references for the event handler, change all of them to this pattern

```
$("#btn_next1").on("click", function() {
    next("index.html#pagetwo"));
});
```

---

When you call a function with parenthesis the function is executed immediately and the result is returned, that means you can reference a function directly if you don't need to pass arguments

```
$("#btn_next1").on("click", next);
```

But you can't do

```
$("#btn_next1").on("click", next(argument));
```

then you would have to do

```
$("#btn_next1").on("click", function() {
    next(argument);
});
```